# How is a table like a mathematical relation?

Tags: math, relational-database

I have been recently been reviewing Codd's relational algebra and relational databases. I recall that a relation is a set of ordered tuples and that a function is a relation that satisfies the additional property that each point in the domain must map to a single point in the codomain. In this sense, each table defines a finite-point function from the primary key onto the space of the codomain, defined by all the other columns. Is this the sense in which it is a relation? If so, why is relational algebra not functional algebra and why not call it a functional database instead?

Thanks. 
BTW, sorry if this is not quite a  normal form for stackoverflow (hah, a DB joke!) but I looked at all the forums and this seemed the best.

Comment: "why is relational algebra not functional algebra" - all functions are relations, but not all relations are functions.

Comment: It's easy to get tripped up on all the definitions when starting out. Conceptually, a relation (table) is like a set or bag of items (rows), but a function has a direction, i.e, origin (x) and target (y). Using the primary key (x) like you are saying does constrain it to a function, a more specific type of relation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there is C.J. Date's "An Introduction to Database Systems", and H. Darwen's "An Introduction to Relational Database Theory". Both are excellent books and I highly recommmend to read them both.

Now to the actual question. In mathematics, if you have *n* sets A1, A2, ..., An, you can form their *Cartesian product* A1 x A2 x ... x An, which is a set of all possible n-tuples (a1, a2, ..., an), where ai is an element from Ai. A n-ary *relation* R is, by definition, a *subset* of the Cartesian product of n sets.

Functions are binary relations — they're are subsets of Dom x Cod. But there're relations with higher arity. For example, if we take set Humans x Humans x Humans, we can define, say, a relation R, by taking all tuples (x, y, z) where x and y are parents of z.

Now there is a one important notion from logic: *predicate*. A predicate is a map from a Cartesian set A1 x A2 x ... x An to set of statements. Let's look at the predicate P(x,y,z) = "x and y are parents of z". For each tuple (x,y,z) from Humans x Humans x Humans we obtain a statement from it, true or false. And the set of all tuples which give us true statements, the predicate's *truth set*, is... a relation!

And notice, that having a *truth set* is all we actually need to work with a predicate. So, when we model our enterprise, we invent a bunch of predicates which describe it, and store their truth sets in the relational database.

And so, each operation with relations has a corresponding operation with predicates, so when we take relations, join and project and filter them, we end up with a new relation — and we know what predicate's its truth set is: we just take the corresponding predicates, and AND them, and bound with existential quantifiers, and we get a new predicate, whose truth set we know.

Edit: Now, I have to note that since relation is a set, its tuples are not ordered. So a table is just a *model* for a relation: you can take to different tables which will represent the same relation. Also, it is customary in relational theory to work with more generally defined tuples and Cartesian products. I defined higher the tuple as (a1, a2, ..., an) — basically, a function from {1,2,...,n} to A1 U A2 U ... U An (where i's image must be in Ai). In relational theory, we take a tuple to be a function from { name, name', ..., name } to A1 U A2 U ... U An — so, it becomes a *record*, a tuple with named components. And of course, it means that record's components are not ordered: (x: 1, y: 2), a function from { "x", "y" } to N which maps x to 1 and y to 2, is the same tuple/record as (y:2, x: 1).

So, if you take a table, swap rows, swap columns (with their headers!), you end up with a new table, which represent the same relation.

Comment: What a great explanation.  I had been thinking of the relations within a table, not generically enough.

Answer (score 0):

[This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) goes into detail about the rationale behind the model.  Conceptually, the key is just a means of accessing a given tuple, not part of the tuple itself--see also [Codd's 12 rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules), #2.